What is the cohomology of a polynomial ring of a cochain complex?
I am struggling to compute the cohomology of a polynomial ring of a fixed cochain complex. Starting with the simplest case, consider a two-step cochain complex of vector spaces
$$
V := V_{0} \xrightarrow{D} V_{1},
$$
where the subscript denotes the cohomological degree of the vector space. In this case, $H^{0}(V) = \ker D$ and $H^{1}(V) = V_{1}/\mathrm{im}(D)$ are the only nontrivial cohomology groups.
One can then consider the polynomial ring of $V$ in the usual sense as $\mathrm{Sym}(V^{*})$. Note that because $V$ is concentrated in degrees $0$ and $1$, $V^{*}$ is concentrated in degrees $0$ and $-1$, and so $\mathrm{Sym}(V^{*})$ is concentrated in all nonpositive degrees. The differential $D$ gets uniquely extended to $\mathrm{Sym}(V^{*})$ by invoking the Leibniz rule.
My question is as follows: how do we compute $H^{k}(\mathrm{Sym}(V^{*}))$ for all $k \in \mathbf{Z}_{\leq0}$? Moreover, does our knowledge of $H^{0}(V)$ and $H^{1}(V)$ help us in a significant way?
My basic attempt so far has been to try to find the right filtration(s) to invoke spectral sequences, but my skill there is somewhat lacking. Also, this feels like something that should have been done at some point, so if someone could point out a text or post where this has been worked out, it would be appreciated!
